# How to make players go to bed without them doing it (with command blocks)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an adventure map and I am trying to create a scene where you are coming home and mom welcomes you and says that you need to go to bed.

Comment: Not exactly possible, the player has to click.

Answer (score 1):

Okay got an answer. Actually I am going to teleport players in a black box and going to give them invisibility so they can't see their hand.